# How to loop through sorted array controller in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Could you tell me the "best" way to loop through items with an ArrayController in Ember 1.9.1?

Let's take an ordered list of users as our example.

Previously I would have done this:

```
<ol>
    {{#each itemController='user'}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

In version 1.9+ I understand this style has been [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope).

**Question one, am I correct to loop over the model? Like this:**

```
<ol>
    {{#each user in model itemController='user'}}
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

**Question two, what if I want to use the controller sort functionality? Can I do this:**

```
<ol>
    {{#each user in arrangedContent itemController='user'}}
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

**Question three, are there any other (more optimal) ways of looping over data with Ember?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Yes**

**2. Yes**

**3. Not as of today (due to Handlebars internal functionality).**

Comment: Thanks, Eric. That helps a lot, I have a bug where Ember fails to render when I use `arrangedContent` but will render if I use `model`. I couldn't work out if the issue was my template or my controller. Sounds like the controller!

Comment: Ember is a bit iffy to render sometimes. Make sure `arrangedContent` is populated _before_ the Controller starts to render it's view(s). Typically you can have your custom-array depend on some model-value (by `.observes()`). Then it will be re-renderd when that asynchronous have loaded.